# How to SUMIFS a dynamic column?

Tags: excel, dynamic, sumifs

I'm using the SUMIFS function in Excel, how do I make the sum range and criteria range to be dynamic?

=SUMIFS(Sheet1!I2:I1040000,Sheet1!J2:J1040000,"PKT*",Sheet1!G2:G1040000,{"BCPF  ","EHQ   "})

Comment: Why can't they be full columns? What is supposed to terminate the 'dynamic' range?

Comment: Why do you have trailing spaces in `{"BCPF ","EHQ "}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that formula should have a SUM(...) wrapper to facilitate the OR condition for column G.

Why do you have trailing spaces in `{"BCPF ","EHQ "}` ?

This SUMIFS from row 2 to the row with the last number in column I.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet1!I2:index(Sheet1!I:I, match(1e99, Sheet1!I:I)),
            Sheet1!J2:index(Sheet1!J:J, match(1e99, Sheet1!I:I)), "PKT*",
            Sheet1!G2:index(Sheet1!G:G, match(1e99, Sheet1!I:I)), {"BCPF ","EHQ "}))
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary or even an issue; SUMIFS uses full column range references without calculation penalty.

Comment: the trailing spaces are correct, because the ERP generate spaces into the Excel file.